# Jest test case for dropdown in Reactjs web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

How to write test case for dropdown related function which sets default value to the clicked one. Here is my function:

```
setDefaultValue = (value, options) => {
    let matchedLabel = options.find(el => el.value === value);
    return [{ value, label: matchedLabel.label }]
}
```

`options` is an array of objects like:

```
options = [
    { value: "", label: "" }, 
    { value: "R", label: "R - Reinvest" },
    ...
]
```

Comment: I believe `setDefaultValue` is internal function that is used internally by component. It's better to validate against render results - so how is this function's return is used?

Comment: its used inside input tag <input default={this.setDefaultValue(dividend, dividendOpt)} />